# "sells", "tastes" -- are these verbs?

Tags: grammar, verbs

> - I am eating an apple that **tastes** strange.
> - I bought a house in    this neighbourhood, because I know it **will sell** for a lot of money    in the future.
> - I followed your cooking instructions, but still the onions **browned** strangely.

Are these bolded words verbs? Because there seems to be something strange about them:

- "I taste too much salt, when I eat your food" seems to be me actively
  doing something (tasting). What the heck does it mean for an apple to
  "taste", then?
- "I sold you a car" seems to be me actively doing something (selling).
  What the heck does it mean for a house to "sell", then?

Questions:
1. Are the bolded words verbs?
2. Is my observation correct that these bolded words seem strange, almost "not active"? Is there a linguistic concept for these kind of words?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "*sell*", "*taste*" and "*brown*" are verbs.(taste = a linking verb)

> I am eating an apple that tastes strange.

It means:

> I am eating an apple that gives a strange taste.

If something tastes strange, it means that you feel strange when you taste it.

"Taste" is not an active verb, it is a linking verb.

The other question, "**sell**" is an active verb.

> If something **sells** for 5 dollars, it means that you can sell it for 5
>   dollars.

"*Brown*" is also an active verb it means getting ready to be eaten. You can have a look its definition on the Cambridge dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty you have seems to be that you imagine that only living creatures can become the subjects of verbs or, at least, the verbs you mention.

But think of a few exceptions (to your imagined rule) that we use all the time.

When you say **the car looks new**, the car is not doing the looking. It's the viewer who is looking at the car.

When the say **the meal smells wonderful**, the meal is not doing the smelling, it's your nose - or, at least, it's you.

So when we say **an apple tastes sweet** we mean that the apple causes a sweetness reaction in our taste buds. Of course it's not the apple that is tasting the eater.

And when we say **an object sells for X amount** we mean that X amount is the market value of the object. It doesn't matter that a person is doing the selling and not the object.

This is a way of speaking that we use constantly.

If you are in doubt about what parts of speech a word can form, look it up. There are several classes of verbs but they are not important to these illustrations.

Comment: it's not so much that i am thinking that only living creatures can be the subject. it's that the subject is not doing the "verb"-ing, but instead someone else is doing the verb to the subject, (as you point out: "the car looks new" - the car is not doing the looking).

this seems like a very strange category of verbs. i'm wondering if there is a linguistical category / word to describe these kinds of verbs. i also notice that these verbs seem to take an adjective ("new", "wonderful", "sweet"). there is a pattern here, and i want to know the lignuistical category behind it.

Comment: @silph Most of the verbs that work this way are stative verbs. Take a look at: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/intermediate-grammar/stative-verbs